# Generate random unitary matrix with given $\theta$

Tags: matrices

For orthogonal matrices, I use this procedure:

```
function random_orthogonal(n, θ)
    X = randn(n, n)
    Y = X - X'
    Y *= sqrt(2) / frobenius_norm(Y)
    return expm(θ*Y)
end
```

For unitary matrices, this is what I tried:

```
function random_unitary(n, θ)
    X = randn(n, n) + rand(n, n)*im
    Y = X - X'
    Y *= sqrt(2) / frobenius_norm(Y)
    return expm(θ*Y)
end
```

(`'` is the conjugate transpose function.)

If we let $\theta$ be a random value from $[0, 2 \pi]$, then `random_orthogonal` produces the expected distribution of eigenvalues.  However, `random_unitary` does not.  What am I doing wrong?

(I realize this isn't the most computationally efficient way of doing this; I'm just trying to understand it from a theoretical perspective.)

Comment: two questions: what happens here "Y *= sqrt(2) / frobenius_norm(Y)" and what exactly is not working? as far as I can say both algorithms should produce (without the line in question) orthogonal/unitary matries